# Open http:// links from Notepad++ to default web browser

Tags: browser, notepad++, links

Can I open *http* links from a notepad++ document directly to my default web browser? Like textpad: CTRL + Click ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Since (at least) Notepad++ 6.3.3, the feature is enabled by default and it is sufficient to **double click** the link.

Related [documentation](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/).

---

In Settings > Preferences > Cloud & Link > **Clickable Link Settings**, click ☒ Enable.  Reload Notepad++ document to show underlined links.  Double-click underlined links to launch in default web browser.

Note this was the default setting right after I installed the version 8.2 of the program.

Comment: There seems to be a bug on Notepad++ 6.3.2, the option is checked by default but it doesn't get effective until you uncheck it and re-check it, save settings and restart Notepad++.

Comment: Same with v.6.5 I had to re-enable it and restart Notepad++ and there you go: just double click. Thanks!

Comment: In 6.3.3 it is enabled by default and ut works if you DOUBLE CLICK it.

Comment: As for version 6.6.9 there's still the same bug. Thanks @マルちゃんだよ for the useful info.

Comment: Great to find this. BTW: Is there a way to change DblClick into Ctrl+Click?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in v6.9.2. Although the whole link is highlighted, only part of the link actually does anything on DblClick. I found this to be a particular problem with (e.g.) Google Maps "street view" links.

Comment: Good to know that it is a double-click, not a single-click, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have Notepad ++ 6.9.2. [Here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Clickable_Links) is the answer provided by the "official" documentation. Starting from the Settings dropdown menu:

[image: The Notepad++ Clickable Link setting]

> The `Settings -> Preferences -> MISC -> Clickable Link` Settings group
>   box has two checkboxes. The upper one is meant to enable or disable
>   the facility. When checked, the lower checkbox becomes enabled and
>   controls whether links are shown with an underline, like most browsers
>   do. If you change the setting during an edit session, you may need to
>   force text being restyled for the changes to apply.
>
> When the mouse hovers over an active link, the pointer changes to the
>   familiar hand shape, and **double clicking the link opens it in your
>   default browser.** Whether the new page is shown in a new tab or
>   window depends on the settings of the browser.

Comment: #@GrumpyMiyagi I have updated the accepted answer with the current application behaviour and the link to the documentation you have provided.

Comment: @GrumpyMiyagi I believe now you can edit your answer and post directly the image.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an update, in the current version (8.X) the option is under "Cloud/Link":

[image]